# map with key and pair values in c++

Tags: c++

I have the following text file:

```
0x2c200000 -3 1
0x2c200002 1 0
0x2c200004 -3 1
0x2c200006 2 3
0x2c200008 -1 2
0x2c20000a -2 1
0x2c20000c 3 1
```

I try to make an std::map from this text file where the first column is the key and the second & third are a pair value. I am using this simple code to do that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

typedef std::pair<int,int> ffp;
FILE *map;
std::map<int, ffp > m_idmap;
std::map<int, int> m_onOffmap;

void IDTest_3() {

 // Init the Id maps

 map = fopen("test1.txt","r");
 if(map==NULL){
 std::cout << "Do not have idmap text file !" << std::endl;
 return;
}
int id,BarEndCap,Sampling;

for(unsigned i=0; i<23; ++i) {

   if ( fscanf(map, "%d %d %d", &id, &BarEndCap, &Sampling) !=3 )
     {
         std::cout << "Corrupted file ? "<<std::endl;
         return;
     }
//       m_onOffmap[BarEndCap] = Sampling;
   m_idmap[id] = std::make_pair(BarEndCap,Sampling);
 }

 fclose(map);

 std::cout << " Test Bar endcap " << BarEndCap << std::entl;
 }
```

When I compile this part of the code I get the message "Corrupted file ?" looks like my fscanf doesn't work perfectly. Do you have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you confirm that you got the message when you compiled the code?

Comment: Are you punishing yourself on purpose by using C-style-i/o instead of iostreams?

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to match hexadecimal numbers (the first column) with the `%d` specifier, which expects integers in base 10.

Try with `%x` (hexadecimal only) or `%i` (auto-detection of base) instead!

See [`std::fscanf's` format specifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't pay attention to the %i, thanks. Now when I compile again I get a strange message :  Error: can not call private or protected function IDTest_3.C:35:
  (compiled)   0 pair<int,int>& pair<int,int>::operator=(const pair<int,int>&);
Calling : pair<int,int>::operator=(pair<int,int>);
Match rank: file     line  signature
*        1 (compiled)   0 pair<int,int>& pair<int,int>::operator=(const pair<int,int>&);
*** Interpreter error recovered *** my function is a sample declaration (void function()) with no protection. any idea why do I get that?

Comment: @Gouimoh Working at CERN? :-) I guess that comes from cling/ROOT/... Maybe create another question and post the failing code there.

Comment: yes I am using root to compile this peace of code. I got this message with different releases of root.

Answer (score -6):

```
 std::cout << " Test Bar endcap " << BarEndCap << std::entl;
```

You have `entl` instead of `endl`. With that change, it compiles for me.

Comment: That looks like a typo. OP is complaining about run-time problems.

Comment: The OP was pretty clear that he was complaining about a message he got when he compiled his code. "When I compile this part of the code I get the message ...". Seems unlikely to me that the OP made two mistakes in asking the question.

Comment: Please look at OP's code. `"Corrupted file ? "` is a message *from his own program*.

Comment: There are two possibilities. One is that the OP reported the wrong message -- one mistake. The other is that the OP both made a typo and erroneously stated that the problem was during compiling -- two mistakes. That the OP made two mistakes that perfectly cancelled each other out seems a strange thing to presume. (I'll ask the OP to clarify.)

Comment: OP hasn't stated that the problem was during compiling. Please read carefully: "When I compile this part..." most likely means "This chunk of my code is the one giving me problems", not literally a message during compilation.